# FindFirst always returns null AutomationElement

Tags: wpf, nunit, ui-automation, automationelement

I am trying to test some custom controls with the UI Automated framework. One of my controls has a base class of TextBox and the other inherits from Control. I can find my first control with my tests, however no matter what combination I use of TreeScope and property conditions, I cannot find my second custom control within the window.

I declare the custom control in the XAML like so:

```
<Grid>
    <test:CustomTextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="customTextBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    <test:CustomUserControl Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,62,0,0" Name="customUserControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="119" />
</Grid>
```

I have a sample test like the one below.

```
[Test]
public void TestUsingValuePattern()
{
    // Getting RootElement...
    AutomationElement rootElement = AutomationElement.RootElement;
    Assert.IsNotNull(rootElement);

    // Searching for Test Window...
    AutomationElement windowElement = rootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "TestWindow"));
    Assert.IsNotNull(windowElement);

    // Searching for Custom TextBox control...
    AutomationElement customElement1 = windowElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "customTextBox1"));
    Assert.IsNotNull(customElement1);

    // Searching for Custom User control
    AutomationElement customElement2 = windowElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "customUserControl1"));
    Assert.IsNotNull(customElement2);
}
```

Second assertion always returns null so I can't even get started running tests on it. Any suggestions here on what I could possibly do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you may need to set the [AutomationId property in the XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationproperties.automationid.aspx) for it to show up - it doesn't look like the Name property gets exposed as AutomationId.

You might also want use the [inspect tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521(v=vs.85).aspx) to check that the elements are actually exposed in the automation tree, and have the AutomationId or other properties that you expect.

Answer (score 0):

See check below thread, you need to use AutomationId for each control to get element using it.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/b0892b5c-3850-4518-8063-d4eb5a8d9781/